# Обратная связь и инициативы на интернациональных сайтах

Tags: обсуждение

Коллеги,

На MSE появился пост Николаса [Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/348096), в котором он предложил высказывать в ответах предложения по данному вопросу.

Поскольку не все на русскоязычном сайте знают о происходящем на MSE - мы решили оповестить бОльший круг участников, опубликовав эту тему и у нас.

Если у вас есть предложения и вам позволяет английский - вэлком на MSE, пишите. Если есть предложения, но не позволяет английский - пишите в эту тему ваши мысли - поможем перевести.

Перевод поста:

---

Конечная цель Stack Overflow — создать, с помощью нашего сообщества, библиотеку детальных ответов на каждый существующий вопрос по программированию. Вместе с нашими бравыми участниками мы отправились в изумительное путешествие после запуска Stack Overflow на разных языках за последние несколько лет.

[image]

И мы идём дальше! Если посмотреть на подсайты сети как на один объединённый  интернациональный сайт, то он будет вторым наиболее активным сообществом после Stack Overflow на английском языке (по количеству вопросов в день). Глядя на наши интернациональные сайты и на остальную часть сети Stack Exchange, я ясно вижу, что мы упустили очень важную вещь: мы забываем, что каждый сайт сети чем-то отличается от такого же интернационального сайта. Я имею ввиду, что у каждого интернационального сайта свой собственный “*Двунаправленный канал коммуникации между компанией и сообществом*”.

#### Как сейчас происходит коммуникация между компанией и сообществом?

За период с 01.01.2018 по 15.06.2018 было опубликовано сотрудниками компании:

- на сайте Meta Stack Exchange: 282 ответа.
- на сайте Meta Stack Overflow на русском: 48 ответа.
- на сайте Meta Stack Overflow на испанском: 28 ответов.
- на сайте Meta Stack Overflow на португальском: 10 ответов.
- на сайте Meta Stack Overflow на японском: 1 ответ.
- на сайте Meta Stack Overflow на английском: 412 ответов.

Мне кажется, что если кто-то из компании не говорит на языке сообщества, то он будет в изоляции от остальной части сети. А мы не хотим чтобы такое случалось. Наша философия успеха полагается в первую очередь на наше сообщество. Мы постепенно делаем наши сайты лучшим местом в сети Интернет где можно задавать вопросы и основываемся в этой работе на обратную связь от вас. Без возможности диалога с сообществом, без того чтобы слушать вас — мы вряд ли бы что-то сделали.

#### Как был устроен процесс?

Раньше у каждого интернационального сайта был один выделенный менеджер сообщества, который знал язык сообщества и английский. То, как такие менеджеры сообщества работали с сообществам различалось у каждого сайта сети. Каждый интернациональный сайт имел отдельные инициативы и разные приоритеты задачи, который почти не пересекались между сообществами. Это означает что КМы часто делали одну и ту же работу по решению похожих проблем на разных интернациональных сайтах. И можно было сохранить большую часть усилий работая вместе.

#### Улучшение коммуникаций

Что если мы пойдём другим путём? Что если мы будем способны обмениваться инициативами между интернациональными сайтами, переиспользовать опыт других сообществ и действовать на базе обратной связи от всех сайтов? Первый шаг по направлению к этой цели это наладить коммуникационный канал для существующих идей, инициатив и обратной связи между компанией и сообществами также как и между сообществами.

Самый большой вызов в этой ситуации в том, что все сообщества, включая компанию, разговариваю на разных языках. Это не чья-то ошибка — просто такова реальность. Поэтому я хочу поделиться с вами некоторыми мыслями о том как мог бы работать подобный коммуникационный канал.

## Обратная связь и инициативы на интернациональных сайтах

> **TL;DR**
>
> - Нам нужен канал взаимодействия между компанией и интернациональными сайтами, а так же каналы между сообществами. На текущий момент наилучшее место это MSE.
> - В дискуссиях на MSE стоит вести обсуждения на английском а интернациональные сайты будут продолжать вести дискуссию на своём языке.
> - Инициативы компании будут публиковать на английском языке на MSE и нам нужна помощь волонтёров-переводчиков чтобы публиковать переводы на локальных мета-сайтах.
> - Инициативы сообщества будем публиковать на соответствующих мета-сайтах и их надо переводить для публикации на MSE. И тогда они могут получать распространение среди других сайтов сети на их метах.
> - Мы будем поддерживать дискуссии в синхронизированном состоянии на всех мета-сайтах сети.
> - Когда дискуссия на интернациональном сайте почти завершена нам снова понадобится помощь волонтёров для того чтобы сделать сводку о том, что было сказано сообществом и запостить ответом на MSE.

[image]

За последние несколько лет мы на SOru опробовали несколько интересных инициатив ([например](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/6)), мы начали несколько социальных инициатив ([например](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4191/6)), мы интегрировали / активировали несколько интересных фич движка ([например](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/6)). Меня беспокоит, что большинство этих инициатив даже не были предложены другим интернациональным сайтам. Я думаю, что ситуация на других сайтах сходная: каждый сайт имеет свой набор инициатив, о которых никто не знает за пределами этого сайта.

Это может привести к ситуации, когда очень важные фичи для интернациональных сайтов не будут реализованы в базовом движке только потому что они кажутся нужными слишком малому числу пользователей (если мы посмотрим на на них в контексте одного конкретного сайта сети). Интернациональные сайты не такие большие по отдельности, но, как уже было сказано, все вместе мы занимаем второе место в сети. Если всем сообществам нужна какая-то фича в движке, то я надеюсь, что она получит соответствующий приоритет. Однако первый шаг — это начать обсуждать инициативы совместно.

#### Как распространять инициативы между интернациональными сайтами?

Когда мы думаем о том, как выстроить коммуникации между сайтами мы должны иметь ввиду следующее:

- Процесс должен быть масштабируемым. Представьте себе, что у нас есть сотня интернациональных сайтов. Процесс должен работать для любого числа сайтов без затруднений.
- Автор инициативы не может говорить на всех языках на которых говорят интернациональные сайты.
- Мы хотим чтобы как можно больше людей просмотрело как можно больше инициатив, включая пользователей с различных англоязычных сайтов и сотрудников компании.
- Должен быть предусмотрен способ интернациональным сообществам обсудить инициативу на своём собственном языке.
- Итоги дискуссии на интернациональных сайтов нужно расшарить на остальную сеть - и в частности на все остальные интернациональные сайты.

Учитывая всё это, хочу рассказать как мог бы выглядеть процесс:

1. Автор инициативы (КМ или участник) должен запостить на вопрос на MSE, пометив его специальным тегом (скажем, [international](/questions/tagged/international)). Язык вопроса - английский.
2. Участники кто знают два языка могут выступить волонтёрами: перевести вопрос и запостить его на интернациональную мету.
3. Когда перевод опубликован на интернациональном сайте, переводчик добавляет ссылку на исходный вопрос на MSE. И, пожалуйста, добавьте ссылку в перевод на  MSE. Это поможет поддерживать дискуссию между метами в синхронизированном состоянии.
4. После того, как сообщество обсудит инициативу, нам нужен доброволец, кто опубликует сводку обсуждения на интернациональной мете в виде ответа в топик на MSE. Сводка должна быть на английском. Я думаю, что возможно будет неплохо держать один вики-ответ со сводкой ответов с интернациональных сайтов. В этом случае мы сможем держать такую сводку наверху закрепив её галкой.
5. Если у кого-либо будут мысли по поводу инициативы он может постить их на любую мету, в том числе и MSE.

В случае инициативы сообщества, процесс будет почти такой же, только с одним отличием: инициатива начинается на мете интернационального сайта и её нужно перевести на английский и запостить на MSE. А после этого все шаги идентичны.

Подобный процесс позволит компании понимать все потребности интернациональных сайтов. Также, процесс должен помочь интернациональным сообществам обмениваться идеями по конкретным вопросам, обмениваться инициативами и видеть какие восхитительные вещи происходят у соседей по сети.

### Пожалуйста, расскажите что вы думаете

Мы хотим сделать наши интернациональные сайты лучшим местом в сети интернет для вопросов по программированию на родном языке участника. Первый шаг - создать платформу взаимодействия сообщество друг с другом и с компанией.
Если у вас есть идеи о том, как мы можем улучшить процесс в направлении к этой цели - пожалуйста, сообщите нам!

### Ссылки на эту инициативу на интернациональных метах

- на SOpt: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7308/112052
- на SOes: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3658/324
- на SOja: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2748
- на SOru: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7847/15479
- на RusSE: [Обратная связь и инициативы на интернациональных сайтах](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/339/182097)

Comment: Там в оригинал правки были внесены. Можно из нашего поста взять уже переведённое https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7847/15479